# Keep hover div open after mouseleave and close it with click outside the div window or close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jquery which opens and close the div "shopping_cart" when hover on "shopping_button"

```
$('#shopping_button, .shopping_cart').on('mouseenter',function(){
  $(this).css('z-index','300');
  $(this).css('visibility','visible');
 })
$('#shopping_button, .shopping_cart').on('mouseleave',function(){
  $(this).css('z-index','189');
  $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
  $(this).css('opacity','0');
 });
```

Need help with what I'm trying to achieve is that "shopping_cart" remain open on mouseleave and only close on if click outside the "shopping_cart" div or can add close button inside the "shopping_cart" div to close it.

Thanks guys.

**Edited**

I added the following to above code

```
$('html').click(function () {
    $('.shopping_cart').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

and it does the job, only close the window when click outside "shopping_cart" div, but now if again hover on "shopping_button" it won't open the "shopping_cart" div, on inspect element it shows

```
$('#shopping_button, .shopping_cart').on('mouseenter',function(){
  $(this).css('z-index','300');
  $(this).css('visibility','visible'); <---This Remain Hidden
 })
```

Any Suggestion?

**sorted**
added this into mouseenter funtion

```
  $('.shopping_cart').css('visibility','visible');
```

And vollhhaaaa....:D

Still looking for more clean solution, if anybody have....

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Of course `.shopping_cart` remains hidden, because you moved your mouse over `#shopping_button`, and so with `$(this)` in your function you are only setting visibility for that button, not for your shopping cart element. So rewrite your function to specifically set the visibility of the latter.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check out this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8nrzL7d/2/

```
$('#shopping_button').mouseenter(function(){
   $("#shopping_cart").css('display','block');
})
$('#btn-close').click(function(){
   $("#shopping_cart").css('display','none');
})
$('html').click(function() {
   $("#shopping_cart").css('display','none');
});

$('#shopping_cart').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I've changed a bit your code, but it's simple: I added a button, because it's quicker to be implemented; then I replaced the cart with an `ID` instead of a `class`, because in my experience I had troubles event on classes and jquery.
I used `display: none` instead of `visibility: none`, because I think the cart shouldn't occupy space (or does it have to? See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp))

EDIT: I also added the function to close the cart if you click outside! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) for the explaination!

I hope I helped you...

Comment: Thanks, i already sorted the problem, accepting your answer because it also provide the solution with close button.

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to use css class for formating element:

```
.shopping_cart {
z-index: 189;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
}
.shopping_cart_active{
z-index: 300;
visibility:visible;
}
```

So you add class shopping_cart_active on hover:

```
$('#shopping_button, .shopping_cart').on('hover',function(){
$(this).addClass('shopping_cart_active');
});
```

And when you want outside of it  you can use this:

```
$(html).on('click', function(){
$('.shopping_cart.).removeClass('shopping_cart_active');
})
```